# OOP design reaching the type outside the class or create instance inside it

Tags: c#, class, oop, design-patterns

Which is the best way to reach the `BObj_Sf`'s `Sn` when populating the data from SQL Server?

This one

```
public class BObj_Sub
{
    BObj_Sf _Sn = new BObj_Sf();

    public BObj_Sf Sn
    {
        get { return _Sn; }
        set { _Sn = value; }
    }
}
```

or is this one better aspect of the ooP?

```
BObj_Sub sub = new BObj_Sub
 {
    Sf = new BObj_Sf { SAd = SAd },
 };
```

Comment: Irrelevant but you really should reconsider your naming conventions :)

Comment: In one case you have a class definition and the other shows the instantiation of that class. How are these two comparable forms of populating data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your question is more related to good programming practice and `there could be multiple solution or design technique for this question`.

I would create classes like this -

```
// create interface for providing {x} features
public interface IBObj_Sf
{
   ...
   ...
}

// create class which provides {x} features of IBObj_Sf interface
public class BObj_Sf : IBObj_Sf
{
   ...
   ...
}

// now implement BObj_Sub class like -
public class BObj_Sub
{
        // mark as readonly depending it is modifiable or 
        // not withing BObj_Sub's lifecycle
        private readonly IBObj_Sf _Sn; 

        public BObj_Sub(IBObj_Sf sn)
        {
            _Sn = sn;
        }

        public BObj_Sf Sn
        {
            get { return _Sn; }
            private set { _Sn = value; }
        }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
BObj_Sf sf = new BObj_Sf();
BObj_Sub sub = new BObj_Sub(sf);
```

**Advantage :** Tomorrow if you would like to change `BObj_Sf` to some new class `BObj_Xf` then only following lines would be changed along with your new class. -

```
BObj_Xf xf = new BObj_Xf();
BObj_Sub sub = new BObj_Sub(xf);
```

Code in `BObj_Sub` would remain unchanged.